# How can I dynamically construct the contents of a function in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, function

I've come across many articles which don't quite address what I'm attempting to do.  I hope that this isn't a duplicate question.

I am writing a Python script which interfaces with several real-world objects outside of my PC.  I have written classes which contain the functions necessary to interface with those objects.  I have also successfully written a function, not very object oriented in style, which instantiates instances of those classes, gets data from them, and saves it all to a CSV file.  That all works fine.  Where I'm getting tripped up is in trying to make the function more adaptable so that I don't have to re-write it every time I want to add another class instance or get a different data point from a pre-existing instance.

The approach that I'm attempting is to create a list which contains names of class instances and specific function names to get data out of those instances.  I then pass this list to another function.  This other function would ideally create a header for my CSV file (so that the data can be more easily interpreted) and then proceed to gather the data.

Pseudocode:

```
inst1 = my_class_1()
inst2 = my_class_2()
filename = 'fubar.csv'
control_list = ['inst1', 'value1', 'inst2', 'value']

my_fucntion(filename, control_list):
# Code to create a header for CSV file in the form inst1-value1, inst2-value2
# Loop to control the number of times to grab data
    # Code which iterates control_list and builds up things like inst1.value1(), inst2.value2(),
    # etc. and then appends the results to a list
    # write results list to filename
```

If I pass all elements of control_list into my function as strings I can easily generate my header for the results file but I can't figure out how to take those strings and generate something like `inst1.value1()` so that Python will access the functions within my classes.  I think that if I create the list like `[inst1.value1(), inst2.value2()]` I can get data from my classes but I can't figure out how to create my header file this way.

I'm open to other approaches if the approach I outlined above won't work.

Comment: Is there a reason you are passing in the strings rather than the classes themselves? Then you can just instantiate the class, whatever class is passed in.

Comment: I may not have made my pseudocode clear.  I am trying to pass in instances of the classes.  I want to be able access the names of those instances (as strings for my data header) and also to access methods of those instances to get my data.  Passing in strings is just something I tried so that I could easily create my header.  I had hoped to use those strings to access methods on my instances.  As I said earlier I'm open to other approaches.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this work without use of other python predefined function with help of oops concept.

class MyClass(object):
    def **init**(self, value1):
        self.value1 = value1

inst = MyClass("example")

get the value of attribute
inst.value1

set the value of attribute
inst.value1 = "hello"

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) function:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, value1):
        self.value1 = value1

instance = MyClass("example")
fieldname = "value1"
fieldvalue = getattr(inst1, fieldname)
# fieldvalue == "example"
```

With `getattr` and `setattr` you can write code that manipulates fields whose name you pass in to your function as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue and used `namedtuple` to solve it.

```
value1 = 'value of 1'
value2 = 'value of 2'
ControlList = namedtuple("ControlList", "inst1, inst2"))
controllist = ControlList(value1, value2)

>>> print controllist.inst1
... 'value of 1'
>>> print controllist.inst2
... 'value of 2'
```

value1 and value2 need not be strings, they can even be instanciated or uninstaciated classes.

The benefits of writing ControlList this way, is that you can always expand your control list, and it doesn't break functions that rely on ControlList being a certain length, or having certain values in certain places.  You always have access to the items in ControlList via .method binding, and can alias `ControlList.method` internally to your functions if you want to avoid messing with code.

Comment: This seems promising but based on your example I don't quite understand how to apply it to my situation.  I will need to do more research on namedtuple to figure how, or if, I can use it.